# bootstrap container grid not full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap grid container is not full width. See image:

[image]

The container is only the bit at the top.

here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
    <div id="my-row" class="row" style="width:100%">
        <div class="col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: red">
            <h4 class="white light" style="margin-top:0px; padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px; float: left;">WHAT WE GROW</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 panel " style="background-color: yellow ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 panel " style="background-color: blue ">
            <h4 class="white light " style="margin-top:0px; padding: 20px 20px 0px 0px; float: right; color: pink; ">SIGN UP FREE</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-row {
    display: table;
    height:20%;
}

#my-row .panel {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

How do I make the container go the full width?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all use: `.container-fluid` for full width, no need to add `style="width:100%"` if you use it.

Second, remove margin and add full width to row:

```
#my-row {
    display: table;
    height:20%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Remove padding from container-fluid:

```
.no-padding {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">

</div>
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5dpgd2d3/)

Comment: That `padding` trick is definitely wrong as bootstrap implemented -15px `margin` on right and left of `.row` to fill the parent container `padding`. This is defined in their grid system.

Comment: @FarzadYZ margin negative don't remove the padding, so i gonna fix this again.

Comment: I did not say `remove`, the 15px padding on `.container` or `.container-fluid` will be filled with -15px marhin of `.row`. The trick you are talking about must be done on `.col-` clasess.

Comment: Ok. I understood. But it he wants the container with full width. My answer right now solves it.

Comment: Cheers. This was looking good but once it is below a certain size, the container becomes wider than the page.

Comment: I rechecked this it seems the `.panel` class is preventing the col-sm-* to stack.

Comment: Your demo doesn't work unfortunately. Add this code to the very bottom of the html file and then resize the window to be less wide and you will see what I'm talking about. `<div style="height:1000px;background-color: yellow">
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove `width:100%` from the `#my-row` element.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/19sfrjrx/)

Comment: I believe he doesn't want it with padding.

Comment: That doesn't take up the full width for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this css below to the `.container` class..

```
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
```

Add this css below to the `#my-row` id..

```
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
```

View my live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/19sfrjrx/1/)

Comment: It doesn't work. There is a white space on the right side.

Comment: removing `padding` and margin of bootstrap's grid system is not a standard solution.

Comment: It's true Mr "Farzad YZ". But requirment is failed to do with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `container` class you should use the `container-fluid` class. 

This gives the div 100% width.


If you really want to use `container` you can add `!important` after setting the width to 100%. This will override the normal bootstrap styles. But I **do not** recommend this.

Comment: That doesn't take up the full width for me.